# Unable to call the built in mb_internal_encoding method?

Tags: php, mbstring

I'm trying to install indefero on a CentOS 5.3 VMware 'box' and I ran into a problem.
Quite early in the installation I get an error that I've been able to narrow down to this:

```
[root@code /var/www/html]# cat x.php
 <?php
     mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
 ?>
[root@code /var/www/html]# php x.php
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in 
/var/www/html/x.php on line 2
```

I get the same error when calling this script via http through Apache.
Now according to the [PHP manual the mb_internal_encoding function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) should be a builtin in PHP 5.

I have CentOS 5.3 i386 (Linux code 2.6.18-53.1.21.el5 #1 SMP Tue May 20 09:34:18 EDT 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux) and I've installed PHP 5.2.9.

```
[root@code /var/www/html]# php -v
PHP 5.2.9 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2009 06:03:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

I double checked: selinux has been disabled (for now).

How do i fix this?

Comment: Is it really built-in? Call _php -m_ to get a list of the built-in modules.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

mbstring is a "non-default" extension, that is not enabled by default ; see [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) of the manual :

> **Installation**
>
> mbstring is a non-default extension.
>   This means it is not enabled by
>   default. You must explicitly enable
>   the module with the configure option.
>   See the Install section for details

So, you might have to enable that extension, modifying the php.ini file (and restarting Apache, so your modification is taken into account)

I don't use CentOS, but you may have to install the extension first, using something like this *(see [this page](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mbstring-php-extension-not-found-phpmyadmin/), for instance, which seems to give a solution)* :

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

*(The package name might be a bit different ; so, use yum search to get it :-) )*

Comment: after you do yum install php-mbstring is there somethingi you need to do after that? I tried apachectl restart but no dice

Comment: `yum install php70w-mbstring` for php7 and yes needs a restart `apachectl restart`

Comment: For Ubuntu, one can use `apt install php-mbstring` and then, of course, restart apache with `systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: @PascalMARTIN its working for me... but i am not able to restart the apache server in `centos`. please help.

Answer (score 26):

For Debian/Ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` in more recent distributions.

Comment: @blue112, what do you mean? I believe if you are using php7.0 then run php7.0-mbstring. If you are running php8.1, then run php8.1-mbstring.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know how to enable php_mbstring extension in windows, open your php.ini and remove the semicolon before the extension:

change this

```
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

to this

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

after modification, you need to reset your php server.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is having trouble with installing `php-mbstring` package in ubuntu do following

 `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

Comment: Also worth noting that if using php7.0 from the ondrej/php repository the correct package is php7.0-mbstring.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get install php7.3-mbstring` solved the issue on ubuntu, php version is php-fpm 7.3

Answer (score 2):

For php 5.6 in ubuntu

```
sudo apt install php5.6-mbstring
```

Restart Apache2

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

For OpenSUse (zypper package manager):

```
zypper install php5-mbstring
```

and:

```
zyper install php7-mbstring
```

In the other hand, you can search them through YaST Software manager.

Note that, you must restart apache http server:

```
systemctl restart apache2.service
```