# Responsive Filemanager 9 opens blank dialog in TinyMCE 4

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce-4, responsive-filemanager

I'm trying to configure Responsive Filemanager 9 (http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) for my project using TinyMCE4

My folder structure are:

TinyMCE:

```
http://localhost/tinyPaintWeb/
http://localhost/tinyPaintWeb/index.html
http://localhost/tinyPaintWeb/plugins/responsivefilemanager
```

Filemanager

```
http://localhost/filemanager
```

source folder (just for testing)

```
http://localhost/lesFiles
```

I'm following the documentation instructions as follows:

config.php

```
$base_url="http://localhost";   
$upload_dir = '/lesFiles/';
$current_path = '../lesFiles/';
$thumbs_base_path = '../lesFiles/thumbs/';
```

index.html (tiny configuration)

```
plugins: ["compat3x print pagebreak fullscreen code image table paintweb responsivefilemanager",],

        image_advtab: true,

        external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
        filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},

       toolbar: "undo redo pagebreak | bold italic | table | paintwebEdit image responsivefilemanager | fullscreen",
```

the file manager icon appears in the Tiny, but when i click it, only appears a dialog with the title "Responsive Filemanager" and blank content.
what i missing???

thank you

Comment: turn on error reporting:
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: sorry D: where i put it?

Comment: at the top of config.php should work

Comment: -.- mb... this appears: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in /var/www/html/filemanager/config/config.php on line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the mbstring extension in your php settings:
see: [Unable to call the built in mb_internal_encoding method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216274/unable-to-call-the-built-in-mb-internal-encoding-method)

Comment: OH YEAH!!! SUCCESS, first of all i need to install it, i'm running Fedora 20 (http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mbstring-php-extension-not-found-phpmyadmin/) then i will need to configure it in a CentOS server, i hope that works there too
Thank you so much