# How to convert view to pdf in php codeigniter using mpdf?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

As I am new to CodeIgniter, I am trying to convert a view to PDF using `mpdf`, but I am getting following error :

> Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding()

And the code in my controller file is:

```
public function DownloadPDF()
{
   $this->load->library('M_pdf');
   $data =array('id'=>'1',
                'name'=>'test'
               );
   $html=$this->load->view('user/Invoice', $data, true); 
   $pdfFilePath ="mypdfName-".time()."-download.pdf";
   $pdf = $this->M_pdf->load();
   $pdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
   $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
}
```

Please, can anyone help me to solve this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to install it - what server are you running?

Comment: I am using apache server.What should i need to install?

Comment: A quick google reveals this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216274/unable-to-call-the-built-in-mb-internal-encoding-method

Comment: Why you use mpdf. You can also use fpdf. This is simple and you can integrate easily.